can't find launchpad content
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal
Release   404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443] Err:14
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu disco
Release   404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443] Hit:15
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease Err:16
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jammy
Release   404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443] Err:17
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]

that's what i get when i am using repository command, like:
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu disco
main

(i tried "fort", same thing)
and other's
what do you think, what should i do

please format error messages as code, not as block quotes

Please remove this ppa it is old (antik).

I think you shouldn't add ppas from 3 different Ubuntu releases to your system.

Opening the first link in your details (https://launchpad.net/~gwibber-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) shows a Personal Package Archive that hasn't been touched/maintained for over a decade, thus has NO SUPPORT for any supported release. Did you check it? as PPAs are not checked being Personal Package Archives, so the only security checks are those you perform yourself. Unless you're trying to infect a modern system with ancient software; why did you add it??

If you are using Ubuntu 22.04, its codename is jammy. The PPA you add must have packages for jammy then. It isn’t the case of the PPA you added; that is why you get 404’s.
By the way, the Gwibber project has been dead for over a decade; it was replaced by an app called “Friends” that has also been abandoned by now. Social media client apps in general have turned into an obsolete niche since website owners have decided to close off their APIs in the 2010s.
